# Should journald be part of logs tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I do know there is a special tag for `systemd-journald`, but I believe it to be special case of `logging`, synonym of `logs`.

My issue being in the definition of `logs` (emphasis mine):

> Configuring or analysing log files (**text** files where programs output error and informational messages, useful for debugging and troubleshooting).

journald actualy saves data in binary form so my question is whether we should ignore this difference, don't use the `logs` tag with journald questions or somehow change the tag.